# Nginx не разрывает соединение с node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx

Задний конец на node.js.

В одном из кейсов нужно обязательно руками обрабатывать разрыв http соединения (например, если коварные русские хакеры перепилили бензопилой "Дружба" кабель-канал с витой парой, при этом безумно хохоча и выкрикивая богохульства).
Подписываюсь req.on('close', () => {что-то делаю...}), тестирую локально - все отлично.
Но на проде нода висит за nginx. И когда соединение рвется между браузером и nginx, то между nginx и нодой соединение не рвется, и мой обработчик не срабатывает.

Можно ли как-то переопределить такое поведение nginx?

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 204800;
        # set client body size to 2M #
        client_max_body_size 3200M;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sites-available/default:

```
><server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80 default_server;

       root /home/superuser/serverside/static/;
       index index.html;

       location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                }

        location /api/ {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:2222;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 }

        location /socket.io/ {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:2222;
                 proxy_http_version 1.1;
                 }
}
```

в обработчике для примера пишу:

```
req.on('close', (e) => {
   console.log('close!');
   console.log('e:');
   console.log(e);
});
```

В консоли вижу:
close!
e:
undefined

Comment: конфиг nginx в студию, версию nginx в студию, код обработчика события `close` в студию

Comment: @norbornen вопросы конечно правомерные, спасибо. я, если честно, в конфиге nginx ничего не понимаю так что туда даже не смотрел. Но сейчас, конечно выложу.

Comment: Если у клиента отключили свет, то разрыва http соединения не будет

Comment: @andreymal Ну может не свет отключат. Это синтетический пример. Для воспроизведения кейса я руками закрываю браузер. Суть не в том, почему соединение разорвалось, а в том, что этот случай мне надо обработать.

Comment: Просто осторожнее с такими примерами, если вы вдруг понадеетесь отловить именно отключение света, то обломаетесь :) Но с закрытием браузера всё будет хорошо, да. Возможно, для nginx поможет опция [proxy_buffering off](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering), но это не точно

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, попробую

Comment: С перепиливанием кабеля абсолютно то же самое: разрыва http соединения при этом тоже не будет :)

Comment: @andreymal что, даже если гнусные богохульства при этом выкрикивать?

Comment: @andreymal а на что же мне тогда подписываться, если я хочу обработать и этот кейс? (серьезно)

Comment: @andreymal просто аплоад файла на сервер в этом случае все же прекратится, и я должен этот случай обработать

Comment: Ни на что. Разрыв соединения с точки зрения интернетов — это отправка TCP-пакета RST или FIN. Отключение света или перепиливание витой пары не приводят к отправке такого пакета и не являются обрывом соединения: если свет по-быстренькому включить обратно (а у клиента ноутбук на аккумуляторе и он не выключился) или по-быстренькому склеить витую пару, то соединение продолжит свою работу как ни в чём не бывало и отправка файла продолжится! Если ни на клиенте, ни на сервере не установлены таймауты, то передача файла может быть продолжена когда угодно, хоть через несколько дней

Comment: @andreymal ясно, спасибо

Comment: Если продолжение передачи файла «хоть через несколько дней» для вас неприемлемо, то установите приемлемые для вас таймауты где-то в настройках nodejs или nginx (где и как конкретно, я, к сожалению, не в курсе) — по истечении таймаута соединение будет считаться оборванным (несмотря на то, что на самом деле это может быть не так), и возможно ваш on close даже сработает. На практике обычно никто несколько дней не ждёт, а таймауты ставят в несколько минут

Comment: Как пример чудовищной гибкости соединений можно ещё привести VPN. Допустим, клиент ходит в интернет через VPN и передаёт файл тоже через VPN, При этом на VPN он имеет статический IP-адрес. Злые русские хакеры режут витую пару, и передача файла приостанавливается. Умный клиент забивает болт на проводной интернет и втыкает USB-модем Yota, переподключается к VPN-серверу, маршрутизация до IP-адреса клиента обновляется — и передача файла продолжается уже через мобильный интернет без разрыва соединения :) Продвинутые роутеры (лично я пользовал Keenetic) умеют делать всё вышенаписанное автоматически.